# Capabilities of the Analytical Hierarchy Process (AHP) in conjunction with weighted overlay tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics

I am making a prospective map of fossil deposits using the "Weighted Overlay" ArcGIS tool. Input factor rasters are mostly topographic in nature (elevation, roughness, TPI, etc). Initially, I  had planned on assigning the weightings of each factor based on expert opinion. However, due to the large number of input rasters it is now apparent that a less subjective, statistical technique of determining these weights would be preferable. I want to know if the analytical hierarchy process (AHP) can be suitably applied to determine the weights of the input rasters in this case.

If not, can you suggest any other methods to reduce the subjectivity of the designation of these weightings?

I am using ArcMap 10.2

Comment: This article may be worth reading to better implement AHP within Weighted Overlay environment in ArcGIS, https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12517-016-2308-y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my education in GIS, I met some statistical methods, however I never encountered better, than AHP for weighting objectively. Unfortunately, there was only one software which provided built-in AHP support (surprisingly an entire wizard) for this purpose: IDRISI. There are some user scripts for ArcGIS, like [AHP 1.1](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=13764) or [AHP-OWA 2.0](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=14894), which has Ordered weighted averaging. You should try these scripts and if they refuse to work, than you can always use a spreadsheet, a pen and a piece of paper or an [online AHP calculator](http://bpmsg.com/academic/ahp_calc.php).

Just remember, you consistency ratio must be under 10% or 0.1. :)

Answer (score 3):

This tool might be of benefit to you if you want to convert your rasters to vector.  There is a OWA function and a WLC(weighted linear combination) there appears to be support for ArcGIS 10.1 and above.

http://mcda4arcmap.codeplex.com/  and a paper http://www.ryerson.ca/~crinner/pubs/Pages12-13_from_Cartouche86_Winter-Spring2013.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are after experimentally but you may want to investigate a [Weights of Evidence](http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=WeightofEvidence/WeightofEvidenceWoEIntroductoryOverview) approach.

Comment: Yes, WoE a data driven approach should be considered as an alternate to AHP to calculate factor weights if reasonable number of training samples are in hand.